# How to serialise and deserialise a recursive sealed trait with Play Json?

Tags: scala, play-json

The following gives me a stack overflow error and I can't figure why it is happening.  I also tried to make the implicit formatter for the recursive type lazy but I get the same error.  Any ideas please?

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

sealed trait Foo

object Foo {
  implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = Reads[Foo] { json =>
    (json \ "discriminator").validate[String].flatMap {
      case "Bar" => json.validate[Bar]
      case "Baz" => json.validate[Baz]
    }
  }

  implicit val fooWrites: Writes[Foo] = Writes[Foo] {
    case bar: Bar => Json.toJson[Bar](bar)
    case baz: Baz => Json.toJson[Baz](baz)
  }
}

case class Bar(b: String) extends Foo

object Bar {
  implicit val barFormat: OFormat[Bar] = Json.format[Bar]
}

case class Baz(c: String, as: Seq[Foo]) extends Foo

object Baz {
  implicit val bazFormat: OFormat[Baz] = (
    (__ \ "c").format[String] and
      (__ \ "as").lazyFormat(implicitly[Format[Seq[Foo]]])
  )(Baz.apply, unlift(Baz.unapply))
}

val baz = Baz("aa", Seq(Baz("bb", Seq(Bar("cc")))))

Json.toJson(baz)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this part of your code to call the correct formatters explicitly:

```
implicit val fooWrites: Writes[Foo] = Writes[Foo] {
  case bar: Bar => Json.toJson[Bar](bar)(Bar.barFormat)
  case baz: Baz => Json.toJson[Baz](baz)(Baz.bazFormat)
}
```

Because they are both `Foo`s, before it was recognizing them as such and calling your `fooWrites` again, hence the stack overflow. You could also look at [play-json-derived-codecs](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs), though I've never used it.

Comment: `play-json-derived-codecs` works very nicely :)